# Whether the integral $t^2(\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}|\xi|e^{\frac{-a\xi^4t}{\xi^2+b}} \,d\xi_1 \,d\xi_2)$ is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

Is the integral
$$
t^2\left(\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}|\xi|e^{\frac{-a\xi^4t}{\xi^2+b}}\,d\xi_1\,d\xi_2\right)$$ bounded when $t\rightarrow\infty$? Here

- $\xi=(\xi_1,\xi_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$,
- $|\xi|=\sqrt{\xi_1^2+\xi_2^2}$,
- $a$ and $b$ are fixed positive numbers.

Comment: The original version of this question did not specify $t\rightarrow \infty $ - not sure whether that limit was intended by the OP. If not, one simple way to obtain a bound is to replace $\xi^{4} -b^2 < \xi^{4} $ in the exponent, rendering the integral elementary.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt --- the initial formulation of the question was unclear ("bounded as a function of which parameters"); I asked the author for clarification (in now deleted comments) and edited (and answered) the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that by $\xi^2$ and $\xi^4$ you meant, respectively, $|\xi|^2$ and $|\xi|^4$, switching to polar coordinates, and making the substitution $r=ut^{-1/4}$, we have
$$
I(t):=t^2\left(\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}|\xi|e^{\frac{-a\xi^4t}{\xi^2+b}}\,d\xi_1\,d\xi_2\right)
=2\pi t^2\int_0^\infty dr\,r^2\exp\Big(-\frac{tar^4}{r^2+b}\Big)
=2\pi t^{5/4}J(t),$$
where
$$J(t):=\int_0^\infty du\,u^2\exp\Big(-\frac{au^4}{t^{-1/2}u^2+b}\Big).$$
By dominated convergence, as $t\to\infty$,
$$J(t)\to J(\infty):=\int_0^\infty du\,u^2\exp\Big(-\frac{au^4}{b}\Big)\in(0,\infty).$$
So,
$$
I(t)\sim2\pi J(\infty) t^{5/4}\to\infty$$
as $t\to\infty$. In particular, $I(t)$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

For $t\gg b^2$ the integral
$$I=2\pi t^2\int_0^\infty \xi^2e^{\frac{-a\xi^4t}{\xi^2+b}}\,d\xi$$
is dominated by the region $\xi\ll\sqrt{b}$, where we may approximate $\xi^2+b$ in the denominator of the exponent by $b$, and then we see that $I$ increases without bound as $t^{5/4}$.
Here is a plot that compares on a log-log plot (for $a=b=1$) the exact integral $I$ (blue) with the large-$t$ approximation (gold)
$$I_\infty=\tfrac{1}{2} \pi  \Gamma \left(\tfrac{3}{4}\right) \left(\frac{b^3 t^5}{a^3}\right)^{1/4}.$$

[image]